# How to create a file name in Ruby with the element of an array?

Tags: ruby

Say I have an array of some elements, and I want to save the data related to each element in a CSV file. This is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'csv'

category_ID = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 91, 92, 93, 94, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]

CSV.foreach('C:\Users\username\Desktop\Original.csv', :headers=>true) do |row,i|
    category_ID.each {|x|}
        CSV.open('C:\Users\username\Desktop\#{x}.csv', "wb") do |csv|           
            if row[4].gsub(/^[^:]+:\s*/,"") == x
                csv << row[28].gsub(/^[^:]+:\s*/,"")
            end
        end
    end
end
```

So I want my file names to be `-1.csv`, `0.csv`, `1.csv`, ... , `119.csv`. But it is giving an error because of the `#{x}` as the file name. How to correct this? Thanks.

**EDIT:** This is 1 row from the `Original.csv` file:

```
"{""timestamp"""," ""2015-05-10 15",59,"59"""," ""article_category_id"""," ""106"""," ""app_name"""," ""Apple Daily TW"""," ""ip"""," ""111.80.37.218"""," ""app_id"""," ""51ee0d904055aa1539d32523"""," ""datetime"""," ""1431273612198"""," ""edition"""," """""," ""action"""," ""page_view"""," ""article_title"""," ""【溫星母親節】潘若迪竟讓老婆一個人過"""," ""user_id"""," """""," ""menu"""," ""即時新聞"""," ""lon"""," """""," ""platform"""," ""Android"""," ""country_residence"""," """""," ""version"""," ""2.5.2"""," ""page_name"""," ""【溫星母親節】潘若迪竟讓老婆一個人過"""," ""location"""," """""," ""is_registered"""," ""False"""," ""provider"""," """""," ""page_id"""," ""607814"""," ""menu_id"""," ""10002""","  ""article_category"""," ""娛樂"""," ""lat"""," """""," ""article_id"""," ""607814"""," ""country_origin"""," """""," ""udid"""," ""d0155049772de9"""," ""gender"""," """""," ""age"""," """""," ""device"""," ""C6902"""," ""session_id"""," """""," ""push"""," ""N"""," ""os"""," ""4.4.2"""," ""browser"""," """"}",,
```

Comment: shouldn't that be c:\users\username\desktop ? where username is your .. username

Comment: Yeah, true. I modified the actual path, and in doing so I forgot about the `username` part.

Comment: always use interpolation in double quotes

Comment: @ShaileshPrajapati Ok, got it. But even after fixing it, its not producing any output file.

Comment: Could you please show a few lines of your original CSV file? Your code is a bit confusing.

Comment: @EricDuminil I tried posting 3-4 rows from the original csv file, but StackOverflow wouldn't let me because it think I am posting spam. It allowed me to post only 1 row, which I have put now in the question. Other rows are similar.

Comment: Is that really a csv row? It looks like a weirdly exported json string.

Comment: @EricDuminil The data was exported from a server and given to me in a CSV file.

Answer (score 5):

This line is a noop:

```
category_ID.each {|x|}
```

I guess you wanted to:

```
category_ID.each do |x|
  CSV.open("C:\Users\Desktop\#{x}.csv", "wb") do |csv|
    if row[4].gsub(/^[^:]+:\s*/,"") == x
      csv << row[28].gsub(/^[^:]+:\s*/,"")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I see. But even with this code, it is giving the following error: `Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - C:\Users\Desktop\|x|.csv (Errno::EINVAL)`.

Comment: Ah, interpolated string should be in double quotes, please see an update.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't know that! Thanks for sharing this knowledge. Confusing and quirky little language, Ruby.

But now even though the code runs without error, it does not produce any output file. Why could that be?

Comment: Does `C:\Users\Desktop\` really exist, or isn't the user name missing?

Comment: @EricDuminil Yeah, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Change following line

```
CSV.open('C:\Users\Desktop\#{x}.csv', "wb") do |csv|
```

to

```
CSV.open("C:\Users\Desktop\#{x}.csv", "wb") do |csv|
```

**UPDATE**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'csv'

category_ID = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 91, 92, 93, 94, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]

CSV.foreach('C:\Users\username\Desktop\Original.csv', :headers=>true) do |row,i|
    category_ID.each do |x|
        CSV.open("C:\Users\username\Desktop\#{x}.csv", "wb") do |csv|           
            if row[4].gsub(/^[^:]+:\s*/,"") == x
                csv << row[28].gsub(/^[^:]+:\s*/,"")
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Ok, the code now runs without error, but it does not produce any output file.

Comment: @Kristada673 try this `CSV.open("C:\Users\Desktop\#{x}.csv", "a+")`

Comment: No, it wouldn't work either, because the file is not even being created. Not even a blank file.

Comment: @Kristada673. please see update and try.you forget to write `do` after `.each`.remove curly braces.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the small error there, I tried it in the proper way itself. :) No file produced.

Answer (score 1):

For the interpolation problem in single quotes, see the answers of mudasobwa and Santosh.

I presume you still get no output because the weird CSV you use.
To test this open one of the CSV in the simplest way there is, so no other issues can interfere. I added options to handle malformed CSV.
You should see only your data files, nothing else, otherwise filter out the other stuff.
Once you are sure your original CSV is read correctly, then try the writing part.

NB the CSV.foreach doesn't provide an index.

```
CSV.foreach('C:\Users\username\Desktop\Original.csv', :headers=>true, force_quotes: false, :quote_char => "\x00") do |row|
  p row
end
```